# Tell an element to show itself based on the status of others on the page?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 hidden divs on my page, and a visible generic "welcome" message.  To the left of these divs are some items that when clicked, toggles their respective divs (as well as the other divs.)  This is all working as intended.

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
$jq(function() { 
$jq("#fade1").click(function(){ 
    $jq("#div1").fadeToggle(750); 
    $jq("#div2").fadeOut(1); 
    $jq("#div3").fadeOut(1);
    $jq("#welcomediv").fadeOut(1);
}); 
$jq("#fade2").click(function(){ 
    $jq("#div1").fadeOut(1); 
    $jq("#div3").fadeOut(1); 
    $jq("#div2").fadeToggle(750); 
    $jq("#welcomediv").fadeOut(1);
}); 
$jq("#fade3").click(function(){ 
    $jq("#div1").fadeOut(1); 
    $jq("#div2").fadeOut(1); 
    $jq("#div3").fadeToggle(750);
    $jq("#welcomediv").fadeOut(1);
});
});
```

I then tried to add an if statement telling the welcome message to show itself if none of the others are visible, Such as if a user clicked one to fade it in, then clicked it again to fade it out.  Currently to behavior would just leave empty space for the user.

```
        if ($jq("#div1:hidden") && $jq("#div2:hidden") && $jq("#div3:hidden")){
    (function(){
        $jq("#welcomediv").fadeIn(500);
    });
};
```

I have also tried checking the CSS directly, such as

```
if ($jq("#div1").css("display", "none") && $jq("#div2").css("display", "none") &&     $jq("#div3").css("display", "none") {
    $jq("#welcomediv").fadeIn(500);
});
```

or

```
if ($('div.x').css('height') === 'auto') {
$('.y').removeClass('a');
```

}

None of these seem to be working.  The divs still fade in and out when their respective link is clicked, but my if statement just does nothing.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To check if an element is invisible, use:

```
if ($jq(selector).is(':hidden') && ... )
```

You should also be able to check if all three are visible using:

```
if ($jq('#div1:hidden,#div2:hidden,#div3:hidden').length === 3) { ... }
```

Comment: Hm not doing it for me.  I need to check if something is hidden, not visible.  I tried 2 things:  if ($jq("#div1").is(':hidden') && $jq("#div2").is(':hidden') && $jq("#div3").is(':hidden')) and your suggestion above checking all 3 at once but changing it to :hidden. No go.

Comment: what have you got inside the `if` now?  Your first block (with the `function` in it) is completely wrong, but the second one looks OK.